# RecyclerView infinite scroll moves position to first item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a List with RecyclerView, and upon scrolling it will perform an API call to obtain the next set of data, which will be updated onto the list. I did this by using the method outlined in this link: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

So the problem I am having is that, as I scroll down, the new data is loaded and presented, BUT the list jumps back up to the very top/start of the list. Is there a way to prevent the list from moving back to the top, but stay where the new data have been loaded?

Thank you!

My full code can be found at: https://github.com/chao-li/MovieNight.git

The list is initiated as follow:
// create the adapter for the movie list

```
     MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(mMovieListViewData.getTotalMovieDataArray());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // As this is recycler view, requires a layout manager
        //RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


And upon loading the data, the new list is updated as follow:

    // append the temporaryMovieArray to the end of TotalMovieDataArray
                                    mMovieListViewData.setTotalMovieDataArray(
                                            appendArray(mMovieListViewData.getTotalMovieDataArray(),
                                                mMovieListViewData.getTemporaryMovieArray()));

                                    //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyItemRangeInserted()`
                                    MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(mMovieListViewData.getTotalMovieDataArray());
                                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(mCurrentMovieDataLength,
                                            mMovieListViewData.getTotalMovieDataArray().length);

                                    // update the starting position of new datas
                                    mCurrentMovieDataLength = mMovieListViewData.getTotalMovieDataArray().length;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading data second time don't initialize your adapter rather than use same adapter object which you have already initialized & make it global variable, & write this below method in your `Adapter` class:

```
public void setData(MovieData[] movieDatas)
{
    mMovieDatas = movieDatas;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

& call this method from your `MovieListActivity`
Then your List will not jump to top.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has worked for me. I am very new to Android coding, can you please explain to me what is the difference between notifyDataSetChanged(); and notifyItemRangeInserted(); ?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged notify adapter that data set has been changed, But It will not specify what about the data set has changed & it will force Adapter to reload all data & relayout all visible views. Where notifyItemRangeInserted specify where and how much data has been changed. You can use any of them as per your requirement. for more info read document:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Recycler.Adapter provides many thing to do that.

Check it out:

[notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int))